# Elasticsearch Stopwords are not working and /_analyze giving correct response

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 6.5.x and I added multiple under custom analyzer. When it comes to stopword analyzer, I am able to get the response correctly when I check  with **_analyze**, When comes to the reality on my index the search box giving me the results even the stopwords are entered. I am posting my index,mapping any Solution for this.

**Index:**

```
PUT some-index
{
  "settings": {
               "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 4,
            "number_of_replicas": 1,
            "refresh_interval": "60s",

        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_snow", "my_stop","my_synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_snow" : {
                    "type" : "snowball",
                    "language": "English"

                },
                "my_stop": {
                    "type":"stop",
                    "stopwords_path":"/home/elasticsearch-6.5.0/config/stopwords/stopwords.txt"
                },
                        "my_synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "/home/elasticsearch-6.5.0/config//analysis/synonyms.txt"
                    }
            }}
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                    "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                },
                  "url": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": "false",
                    "store": true
                },
                  "host": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true
            },
                "seed": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": "true",
                    "store": true
        }

        }}
    }
}
```

**Query I need to use**

```
POST /some-index/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "test"     /* Tested with and,between*/
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "term" : { "seed" : "ghi" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Tested with /_analyze Works great**

```
POST some-index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text":"Hi this is Ramy."
}
```

Comment: hey @an__snatcher, could you let me know how many servers are being used, did you reboot all the servers after adding the `*.txt` files *in all of them*? I've tried query at my end and it works as expected. Could you also post a sample document which you think shouldn't be showing up but yet shows up in the response.

Comment: Hi @Kamal. If the server means an Elastic Server then I am using one server and Do I need to reboot this server before indexing the data or else after pushing the data into the index.  I am sharing some sample data `Title: About Storm Crawler
Content: StormCrawler is an open source SDK for building distributed web crawlers based on Apache Storm. The project is under Apache license v2 and consists of a collection of reusable resources and components, written mostly in Java.
url: http://stormcrawler.net/
host: www.stormcrawler.net
seed: stormcrawler
`

Comment: @Kamal I restarted my elastic search service but the stopword filter is not applying to the existing indexes and  tried with new indexes but its not working.

Comment: hey @an__snatcher, apologies I missed this. I just saw your stopwords path. Could you change that value to like this`"stopwords_path":"stopwords/stopwords_en.txt"` and give it a try. Yes you would need to restart the nodes to make this change. The config file has to be initialized when ES is starting up.

Comment: I've been able to create mapping (removing syonyms as I don't have the file), the document you've mentioned in the comment and I've tried to query the stopwords. No result appears.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the dictionaries in elastic cloud and re-created the index. still, elastic application is not considering new stopwords. Do I need to reboot the cloud instances to get it reflected ?